# ngx-datatable disabling default white tooltips

Tags: angular, user-interface, tooltip, angular2-template, ngx-datatable

I am working on styling a web app, and was asked to get rid of the default white tooltips on this ngx-datatable, but haven't really found anything on this topic. Are you able to get rid of these?

[image: Problem example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the row cells you can modify them using this css:

```
.datatable-body-cell-label {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

For the header cells it's more tricky because they are clickable to support sorting. Something like jQuery will be needed. Like this:

```
$('.datatable-header-cell[title]').on('mouseenter', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

By the way, those "default white tooltips" are a result of the title attribute which the browser handles on its own, typically showing it on hover.